# unexpected EOF when reading a file in multi process environment

Tags: c, linux, file-io, synchronization

I have a file `instructions.txt` (denoted by file pointer `fp`) which consists of 12 lines (each line containing the bytes `ls\n` and `ps\n` alternatively).

Initially the main process opens the file in read mode, creates and initializes a shared memory area `mem` and creates another 11 processes using `fork()`.

Each of the 12 processes are supposed to read exactly one line from the file and execute that instruction. Before entering the outermost `while` block, calling `ftell(fp)` in all processes returns 0.

The problem is, after the first process that enters the outermost `if` block reads one line using `fgets`, calling `ftell` in other processes returns 36 (the file size is 12x3 = 36 bytes). `ftell` in the process that executed `fgets` first still returns 3 (end of first line).

So the next time any process calls `fgets`, it returns an `EOF`

The shared memory area `mem` is used as an "array" where 1st to 12th elements contains PIDs of the 12 processes and 0th element is used as an index to decide which process will enter the outermost `if` block.

Here is the snippet that is causing the issue -

```
while(mem[0] > 0)
{
    printf("(%u) pos = %ld\n", curr_pid, ftell(fp));

    // only the process whose PID matches the value in 
    // mem[mem[0]] can enter
    if(curr_pid == mem[mem[0]])
    {
        printf("\n\nprocess %u enters CS\n", curr_pid);
        char instr[100];
        printf("pos before read = %ld\n", ftell(fp));
        if(fgets(instr, 100, fp) == NULL)
        {
            perror("fgets error or EOF");
            //return 1;
        }
        printf("pos after read = %ld\n", ftell(fp));
        instr[strlen(instr)-1] = 0;
        printf("process %u executing command: %s, size = %lu\n", curr_pid, instr, strlen(instr));

        /* execute instruction */
        char *args[] = {instr, NULL};
        pid_t exec_pid = fork();
        if(exec_pid == -1)
        {
            perror("fork error");
        }
        else if(exec_pid == 0) // child execs
        {
            execvp(instr, args);
            perror("execvp error");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("process %u leaving CS\n", curr_pid);
        sleep(5);
        mem[0]--; // alow next process to enter and read
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

Here

- `(FILE *) fp` is a file pointer to `instructions.txt` file
- `(int *) mem` is an shared memory attached to all 12 processes
- `mem[0]` is the index (values from 1 to 12 inclusive) at which PID for process to be selected to enter the `if` block is found in `mem` (ie, `mem[mem[0]]` contains the PID of the `mem[0]`th process
- `(pid_t) curr_pid` stores own PID for each process

In essence, only one process enters the outermost `if` block while others "wait" by looping until their turn comes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processes all have streams associated with the same kernel-maintained open file description.  These streams' buffers belong to the processes, but the file offset belongs to the underlying open file description.

Whenever a process reads from a stream with no data already buffered, it very likely reads more data into the buffer than it ends up using right away.  This is what is happening in your case.  The first process to read reads all 36 bytes of the file into its copy of the stream buffer, advancing the underlying file offset to the end of the file.  The processes that afterward attempt to read from the stream do not share the first one's stream buffer; all they see is that the (shared) file offset is positioned at end-of-file.

If you want multiple processes to read cooperatively from the same file, then you'll need to account for that.  I can see at least two mechanisms:

1. In your shared memory segment you also maintain a count of the number of bytes so far consumed.  Each process uses that to perform an `fseek()` to the appropriate position before it tries to read.
2. You use low-level I/O with file descriptors (`open()`, `read()`) instead of stream I/O.  To the extent that you perform any buffering, you maintain the buffer in shared memory.

Note also that you need some form of synchronization to ensure that each process sees writes to shared memory performed by the other processes.  You could provide for that *and* get rid of your wasteful spinlocks by creating and properly using a process-shared mutex and condition variable.